# Creating a List of TableColumn, java swing

Tags: java, swing, generics, jtable

I've seen a few examples on this site where people working with JTables declare the following:

```
 List<TableColumn> columns = new ArrayList<TableColumn>();
```

I'd like to do this too, as my goal is to create a list that will store columns that are hidden from the user (I need the list so that I can un-hide the columns later if need be).

However, when I try the above eclipse tells me:

> The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with
>   arguments

Can someone tell me how to fix this? Or suggest another option?

Comment: consider JXTable (part of [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net)) which supports hidden columns

Comment: @kleopatra hey, JXTable works great! Thanks a lot for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have imported the wrong List class.

Make sure you have `java.util.List;`   As opposed to `java.awt.List;` or some other list.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [Table Column Manager](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/table-column-manager/). It provides hide/show functionality for the TableColumns.

It is designed to allow the user to control which columns are displayed/hidden but you can turn that off by using  `setMenuPopup(false).`